# Populating jTable using List

Tags: java, json, list, jtable, jackson

I have a list of data which I got from my Json file using Json Jackson, how can I populate jTable from this list?

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Bambola","description":"Opis...","contact_number":"022\/349-499","email":"","address":"Svetosavksa 23","geo_latitude":"44.96868000000000","geo_longitude":"20.28140000000000","created_at":"2013-06-24 14:15:08","updated_at":"2013-06-24 14:15:08","deleted_at":null,"publication_starts":"1991-05-24 01:00:00","publication_ends":"1991-05-24 01:00:00"},{"id":2,"name":"Master","description":"Opis...","contact_number":"022\/349-123","email":"","address":"Svetosavksa 24","geo_latitude":"44.96653000000000","geo_longitude":"20.28170000000000","created_at":"2013-06-24 14:15:08","updated_at":"2013-06-24 14:15:08","deleted_at":null,"publication_starts":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","publication_ends":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"},{"id":3,"name":"Tritel","description":"Opis...","contact_number":"022\/321-499","email":"","address":"Svetosavksa 25","geo_latitude":"44.96654000000000","geo_longitude":"20.28170000000000","created_at":"2013-06-24 14:15:08","updated_at":"2013-06-24 14:15:08","deleted_at":null,"publication_starts":"0000-00-00 00:00:00","publication_ends":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]
```

Using the Json Jackson parser I have populated the List with this data.

```
List<Advertisement> advertisements = mapper.readValue(url, new TypeReference<List<Advertisement>>(){});
```

Now I want to populate the jTable, I have used the NetBeans GUI builder to create frame and the table. The table name is advertisementList_JT. So far what I have tried is this snippet of code found in a simillar question here on the site.

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
        for (Advertisement adv : advertisements) {
            Object[] o = new Object[3];
            o[0] = adv.getName();
            o[1] = adv.getPublication_starts();
            o[2] = adv.getPublication_ends();
            model.addRow(o);
        }
        advertisementList_JT.setModel(model);
```

With this snippet the table when I start the application just goes gray and nothing happens, looked thru the debugger and no errors either.

Comment: have look at AbstractTableModel, here are a few very good attempts on last two months

Comment: The basic code you posted looks fine, but we don't know the context of how the code is invoked. If the frame is grey then I would suggest that you don't actually add the table to the frame. Maybe you have instance and local variables. Add some debug statements to you code see if you code is even being executed.

Comment: @mKorbel: Why don't you like the DefaultTableModel?  Most tables don't need a custom table model.

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc be sure I love DefaultTableModel, but I think that for array based on util.List is better to look for (only) AbstractTableModel, and then to use List as underlaying array directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it happens because you didn't supply the table header. See if this works:

```
Object[] columnNames = {"Name", "Starts", "Ends"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[0][0], columnNames);
        for (Advertisement adv : advertisements) {
            Object[] o = new Object[3];
            o[0] = adv.getName();
            o[1] = adv.getPublication_starts();
            o[2] = adv.getPublication_ends();
            model.addRow(o);
        }
        advertisementList_JT.setModel(model);
```

Another possibility is that advertisements List is empty;

Comment: Yes it worked thank you. The column names were the problem T thought if I have written the column names inside the GUI builder they would apply to the table, it looks that with .setModel I replaced all previous configurations done with GUI BUilder.